# How can I use the multidimensional index returned by max or min?

Tags: matlab, multidimensional-array, indexing, max, complex-numbers

In matlab,

```
[M,I] = max(A, [], dim)
```

returns maximum values and the index of those maximum values *along the specified dimension dim*. When A is an multidimensional array, variable I turns out to be a multidimensional array with same dimension as A, except the dim dimension set to 1. My question is how do I use the index multidimensional array I to get back the max from the A.

To provide a specific use case, I want to obtain the complex number with maximum *real part* along the dimension dim, when A could contain complex numbers.

I can use

```
[M,I] = max(real(A), [], dim)
```

to get the maximum real parts and their indices. But, how do I get the original complex variable at those indices? I am particularly interested in cases where A has more than 2 dimensions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `dim` is arbitrary, it's easiest to move it to the first dimension (with [`permute`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/permute.html)) in order to simplify the indexing back:

```
A = randn(2,3,4)+1j*randn(2,3,4); %// example data
dim = 2; %// dimension along which to maximize
Ap = permute(A, [dim 1:dim-1 1+dim:ndims(A)]); %// move dim to 1st dim
[M,I] = max(real(Ap), [], 1); %// minimize function of Ap along 1st dim
ind = I + reshape(0:size(Ap,1):numel(Ap)-1, size(I)); %// build linear indices from I
values = Ap(ind); %// index into Ap to get minimizing values
```

As a check that this works: use `A` non-complex (so `real` does nothing) and compare `values` with `M`:

```
>> A = randn(2,3,4);
dim = 2;
Ap = permute(A, [dim 1:dim-1 1+dim:ndims(A)]);
[M,I] = max(real(Ap), [], 1);
ind = I + reshape(0:size(Ap,1):numel(Ap)-1, size(I));
values = Ap(ind);
values == M

ans(:,:,1) =
     1     1
ans(:,:,2) =
     1     1
ans(:,:,3) =
     1     1
ans(:,:,4) =
     1     1
```

Comment: This is so ugly :p